# How can you compile sass to css with webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, sass

Can't figure out how to compile main.scss file to styles.css with webpack4. 
All javascript and scss are compiled to a single app.js file

```
  My package.json file:
```

[image]

```
webpack.config.js file:
```

[image: webpack config file]

[image: webpack config file]

```
 I want to compile my main file /src/styles/styles.scss to dist/styles.css
```

Comment: Documentation is sometimes worth reading;)
[Extracts CSS into separate files](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#extracts-css-into-separate-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try redefining the use property of the .scss rule.

```
{
test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ]
},
```

Then add this to your plugins:

```
plugins: [
    ...,
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: '[name].css',})
]
```

That should compile it all into the dist/ folder, as a separate .scss file.
Edit: as a separate .css file.*

Comment: Thanks, but I need a css file.

Comment: Sorry @ViktorasssIT I meant to type as separate CSS files. Not SCSS. Sorry.